# How do i grep to find words which contain two z’s and also two a’s

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find words which contain two z’s and also two a’s through a word list? Thank You

Comment: Provide sample inputs with your attempts

Comment: Do you want at least two, two exactly or at most two? Is each string guaranteed to only contain a single word? @klutts answer for example is for "at least two of each letter on one line, no matter whether there are several words".

Answer (score 1):

```
z.*z.*a.*a\|z.*a.*z.*a\|a.*z.*z.*a\|z.*a.*a.*z\|a.*a.*z.*z
```

or as Benjamin wrote in comments below, if you use piping you can simplify it to

```
grep 'z.*z' | grep 'a.*a'
```

Comment: Equivalent: `grep 'z.*z' | grep 'a.*a'`