# How do I grep for all words that contain two consecutive e’s, and also contains two y’s

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find the set of words that contain two consecutive e’s, and also contains two y’s.

So far i got to `/eeyy/`

Comment: show the input text

Comment: This will be much easier using two regular expressions instead of one.

Comment: Are the y's required to be consecutive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i grep to find words which contain two z’s and also two a’s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349482/how-do-i-grep-to-find-words-which-contain-two-z-s-and-also-two-a-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alteration with ERE:

```
$ echo evyyree | grep -E '.*ee.*yy|.*yy.*ee'
evyyree
$ echo eveeryy | grep -E '.*ee.*yy|.*yy.*ee'
eveeryy
```

If the match needs to be in the same word, you can do:

```
$ echo "eee yyyy" | grep -E 'ee[^[:space:]]*yy|yy[^[:space:]]*ee'   # no match
$ echo "eeeyyyy" | grep -E 'ee[^[:space:]]*yy|yy[^[:space:]]*ee'
eeeyyyy
```

Then only that word:

```
$ echo 'eeeyy heelo' | grep -Eo 'ee[^[:space:]]*yy|yy[^[:space:]]*ee'
eeeyy
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified it into `.*ee.*yy.*|.*yy.*ee.* `

Comment: this will also match the words with only `ee` or `yy`, not both. Example: `'eeeyy heelo'`

Comment: Isn't `eeeyy` a match?

Comment: `echo 'eeeyy heelo' | grep -E '.*ee.*yy|.*yy.*ee'` outputs both `eeeyy heelo
`

Comment: Kinda trivial fix, but fixed... Thanks

Comment: You should use awk for this, not grep. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43458788/1745001

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it:

```
$ echo eennmmyy | grep ee | grep yy
eennmmyy
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** approach to match all words that contain both `ee` and `yy`:

```
s="eennmmyy heello thees-whyy someyy"
echo $s | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/ee/ && $i~/yy/) print $i}'
```

The output:

```
eennmmyy
thees-whyy
```

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible and extensible way to do this is with awk:

```
awk '/ee/&&/yy/' file
```

Imagine trying to do it the grep way if you also had to find `zz`. Here's awk:

```
awk '/ee/&&/yy/&&/zz/' file
```

and here's grep:

```
grep -E 'ee.*yy.*zz|ee.*zz.*yy|yy.*ee.*zz|yy.*zz.*ee|zz.*yy.*ee|zz.*ee.*yy' file
```

Now add a 4th additional string to search for and see what **that** looks like!

Comment: For each *word* you need to go through field by field, but point taken.

Comment: No you don't but if you did then it'd be even more reason to use awk.

Comment: `$ echo 'ee yy' | awk '/ee/&&/yy/'` 'ee yy' is not a 'word'. You say you do not need to go through word by word? How?

Comment: I said you don't need to go through it field by field. One possibility: `echo 'ee yy' | awk -v RS=' ' '/ee/&&/yy/'`. But who knows what a "word" is to the OP? It all depends what the OPs input data and desired output look like, neither of which we've seen yet so idk why we're even answering.